# FTP Connection Issues

Tags: centos-7, cpanel

I've installed the cPanel on cloud and enabled tcp port 21 on engine DNS but I still can't login by FTP client and I also changed the default port of PassivePortRange 49152 65534 too but I still can't access either

```
Status: Disconnected from server
Status: Resolving address of ftp.tfo.com.au
Status: Connecting to ...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Initializing TLS...
Status: Verifying certificate...
Status: TLS connection established.
Command:    USER tfotiles
Response:   331 User tfotiles OK. Password required
Command:    PASS **********
Response:   530 Login authentication failed
Error:  Critical error: Could not connect to server
```

Someone, please help me and I don't know what to do.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You're getting a TLS connection established, so a two-way connection to the port 21/TCP actually works. And you are successfully sending a USER command to the FTP server and getting a response back. But after sending the password with the PASS command, the server terminates the connection.

So it's not a firewall issue at this point; it's an authentication issue.

Note that the cPanel documentation says:

> If the account uses a dedicated IP address, you can use your cPanel
>   account's username and password to log in to FTP. Otherwise, you must
>   use the full FTP account username (account, at-symbol, and domain
>   name) and password to log in to FTP.

So try specifying the FTP username as `tfotiles@ftp.tfo.com.au` rather than just `tfotiles`.

If that does not help, please read on...

FTP servers can be configured to allow anonymous connections only (for setting up a public FTP server, that would usually allow only downloads), authenticated users only (which would probably allow uploads too), or both. I think this setting in your FTP server might not be correct.

Also, since you seem to be using SSL/TLS-encrypted FTP (i.e. FTPS), there is another possibility: if authenticated users are allowed, the authentication can happen using passwords (as usual) or with a *client-side* X.509 certificate. If the FTP server is (possibly by mistake) set to accept certificate authentication only, then even the correct password for user `tfotiles` will not work.

Your question tags indicate you're using CentOS 7, but that does not completely identify the FTP server software used: the default FTP server of CentOS 7 is `vsftpd`, but there is also a `ProFTPd` FTP server available for it in a very commonly-used EPEL repository. If you can confirm which FTP server is used, please edit it into your question post.